# Kendo Binding Null value in template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

`Example`

I receive data from server (C# classes Serialization) and some items in arrays is null.
This items breaks all arrays binding.
How to i can ignore this null items and bind all other items

Comment: It would be better to clear-off nulls on server, rather than conditioning client-side. It does not make sense to pass null object to client (json object field can be null though and conditioned using same [template literal syntax](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview)).

Comment: In real world data have more complex and hierarchical structure. If i will validate all data on server side it will very difficult